# What is the meaning of Flavie's final statement?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, french-language, emile-zola

At the end of *Nantas* (1878) by Émile Zola, the last words of the short story are Flavie's final statement:

> <sub>ENGLISH:</sub>
>
> "I love you!", she cried to his neck, sobbing, tearing this confession from her pride, from all her being tamed, "I love you because you are strong!"
>
> <sub>FRENCH:</sub>
>
> « Je t’aime ! cria-t-elle à son cou, sanglotante, arrachant cet aveu à son orgueil, à tout son être dompté, je t’aime parce que tu es fort ! »

Why does Flavie announce her love for Nantas and say that he is strong?

Comment: (The story is available in the original French [here](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Nantas), if anyone wants to check the text before answering.)

Comment: *Announce* is far too mild a word here! *Arrachant* means *ripping* or *tearing* – quite a violent metaphor. She's overwhelmed by him and is “confessing” her love, *in spite of* her pride and her “being tamed” which is actually a word normally used to refer to mastering an animal (e.g. subduing a wild horse!). I'll have a crack at an answer, but I'm anything but an expert on French literature :o)

Answer (score 4):

Warning: very much personal opinion; you should consider posting on the French Language SE for better feedback on the original text. In particular to check on the intended sense of *arrachant*, as I’m a little uneasy about my understanding there.

At first glance I wondered if *arrachant* was meant in the sense of being torn between her pride and "being tamed" could perhaps mean upbringing, but on closer examination that didn't hold up. [*Arrachant*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/arracher/5353?q=arrachant) isn’t the right word for that sense of torn ([*déchiré*](http://lyricstranslate.com/en/Notre-Dame-de-Paris-French-cast-Dechire-lyrics.html)), and [*dompté*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/dompter/26406) here is more about *self-control*.

I get the impression — or I think Zola is trying to give the impression — that she rather hates herself for feeling as she does about him. She’s been *conquered* : she’s a wild horse, he’s the rider.

In other words her confession of love is being torn from her, grating against her usual pride and, for want of a better word, *poise*.